# ¿Cómo llenar el option de un select dependiendo el valor recibido en Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Tengo la siguiente tabla y en el campo **MANUAL**, me llegan dos posibles valores (0 y 1), donde
1 = Si y 0 = no, y necesito mostrar en el select, los valores Si y No, y que este por defaul el valor seleccionado de lo que me trae **{{contr.manual}}**

como puedo implementar el nif en el componente para dicha validacion, o como más?

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="guardar()">Guardar</button>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">ESTADO</th>
                <th scope="col">COMENTARIO</th>
                <th scope="col">MANUAL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let contr of control">
                <td>{{contr.id}}</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="select" (change)="onChangeList($event, contr)">
                        <option value="0">{{contr.cveEstado}}</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado" [disabled]="estatus.cveEstado== 'ERR'? 'disabled': null" [ngClass]="{'text-red':estatus.cveEstado== 'ERR', 'text-blue':estatus.cveEstado== 'INP', 'text-orange':estatus.cveEstado== 'PDD',
                                'text-black':estatus.cveEstado== 'FNZ'}">
                            {{estatus.descripcionEstado}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>{{contr.comentario}</td>
                <td>{{contr.manual}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Update

```
<select class="select" (change)="cambiarManual(contr)">
                                <option value="0">{{contr.manual}}</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let manual of manualArr"
                                    [value]="manual.valor">
                                    {{manual.label}}
                                </option>
    </select>
    
    cambiarManual(contr: any) {
    console.log(
      `Manual: ${contr.manual}`
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un arreglo de objetos donde establezcas los valores se soluciona. Agregué una función para que veas en consola que se imprimen los valores.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Manual</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of tabla">
      <td>{{ row.nombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.estado }}</td>
      <td>
        <select [(ngModel)]="row.manual" (change)="cambiarManual(row)">
          <option *ngFor="let manual of manualArr" [value]="manual.valor">
            {{ manual.label }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Componente**

```
 export class TablaComponent {

  tabla = [
    { nombre: 'Test 1', estado: 'Error', manual: 1 },
    { nombre: 'Test 2', estado: 'En Proceso', manual: 0 },
    { nombre: 'Test 3', estado: 'Finalizado', manual: 1 },
  ];
  manualArr = [
    { label: 'Si', valor: 1 },
    { label: 'No', valor: 0 },
  ];


  cambiarManual(row: any) {
    console.log(
      `Nombre: ${row.nombre}, Estado: ${row.estado}, Manual: ${row.manual}`
    );
  }
}
```

**Resultado**

Por alguna razón no se capturaron las opciones que despliegan en el gif pero puedes ver los cambios.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré. Una consulta , cuando quiero replicar la propiedad [(model)] en el mat select para que por default muestre el valor, en angular 10 no lo hace , hay una propiedad con la que si funcione?  Si lo pruebo en una versión de angular 13 me parece si se ve reflejado

Comment: Te refieres a `[(ngModel)]`?, no sabría en Angular 10, pero te sale un error o simplemente no funciona?

Comment: Más bien en el  [(value)]="row.manual" ,  No marca error , pero simplemente no hace nada , hay una alternativa ?

Comment: En la pregunta que hiciste de establecer el valor de  un `mat-select` por defecto si te funciona? Porque es prácticamente el mismo código. Trata importando el `FormsModule`.

Comment: si me funciona en angular con la version 13, pero en una version 10 no, pero voy a probar importando FormsModule, gracias

Comment: Podrías intentar con `ngModel` también, de igual forma necesitas el `FormsModule`, pero está raro que no funcione en Angular 10.

Comment: pero como pongo el  valor de lo que trae  <td>{{contr.manual}}</td>, que es donde me dice 0 y 1, si lo reemplazo en el arreglo   { label: 'Si', contr.manual}: 1 }, me manda error

Comment: No entiendo porque lo vas a reemplazar, así como esta debería de funcionar.

Comment: es que no entiendo en que momento,se evalua lo que yo traigo de {{contr.manual}} que es con lo que se llena mi tabla , para determinar si va Si o No, es decir, si {{contr.manual}} es = 0 pon un No

Comment: actualice mi pregunta con los cambios que hice, es que no uso material, y asi como esta, lo que hace es que me muetra en el select  el valor  que trae {{contr.manual}} , por ejemplo:  1, Si, No

Comment: Ya quedo editado.

Comment: muchas gracias @René